# error code coming up in hangman game using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to finish up a hangman assignment using JS. I'm trying to finish up the `function processGuess(event)` so that I can run the program on the console and identify any mistakes throughout the rest of my code.
When I run the game, I get as far as inputting a word for another player to guess, but when I "guess" a letter, an error on the console shows up:

> script.js:63 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of
>   undefined at HTMLElement.processGuess (script.js:63).

I'm not sure why this is happening.  The line that the error is referencing to is:

```
document.getElementById("hangman").value.toUpperCase();
```

Javascript code:

```
let word = prompt("Welcome to Hangman! Player 1, please enter a word for Player 2 to guess.").toUpperCase();
// note the switch toUpperCase(), we want to always work in upper case letters to avoid confusing 'a' and 'A' as unequal.

let revealedLetters = new Array(word.length); // creates an array with as many elements as word has characters. Each index of 
//revealedLetters will correspond to a character in word, and if revealedLetters[n] is truthy, then word[n] has been correctly guessed.
revealedLetters.fill(false);

const maxStrikes = 6; 
let strikes = 0; // the number of incorrect guesses made so far

let strikeLetters = new Array(maxStrikes); // this will contain every letter that has been incorrectly guessed.

drawWordProgress(); // run this now, to draw the empty word at the start of the game.

// Manipulates the DOM to write all the strike letters to the appropriate section in hangman.html
function drawStrikeLetters() {
    strikeL = document.getElementById("strikeLetters");
    let strikeText = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < strikeLetters.length; i++){
        strikeText += strikeLetters[i] + ", ";
        strikeL.innerHTML = "<p>" + strikeText + "</p>";
    }
    // your DOM manipulation code here
    // should create a String from strikeLetters and put that into the content of some element.
}

// Manipulates the DOM to write the successfully guessed letters of the word, replacing them with dashes if not yet guessed
function drawWordProgress() {

      let blankProgress = document.getElementById("correctword");
      let blankGuess = document.getElementById("guessword");
      blankGuess.innerHTML = "";
      for(j = 0; j <revealedLetters.length; j++){
          if(revealedLetters[j] != false){
              blankProgress.innerHTML += revealedLetters[j];
          }else{
              blankGuess.innerHTML += " _ ";

          }
      }

    // your DOM manipulation code here
    // should iterate over revealedLetters, and if the value at each index is truthy, print the corresponding letter from word. 
    //Otherwise, it should print a -.
}

// Manipulates the DOM to update the image of the gallows for the current game state.
function drawGallows() {
    event.preventDefault();
    let imgUpdate = document.getElementByTagName("gallowsimg"); //get the img with id "gallowsimg"
    imgUpdate.setAttribute("src", "images/strike-" + strikes + ".png"); //change the img according to number of strikes user has
}


document.getElementById("guess-form").addEventListener("submit", processGuess);

function processGuess(event){
   event.preventDefault();

   let guess = document.getElementById("hangman");

   document.getElementById("hangman").value.toUpperCase();
   document.getElementById("hangman").value = "";

   if(strikes < maxStrikes) {
       let guessIsCorrect = false;
       for(let l of word) {
           if(guess == l){
               guessIsCorrect = true;
               if(guessIsCorrect){
                   for(let t = 0; t < word.length; t++) {
                       if(word[t] == guess){
                           revealedLetters[t] = true;
                           drawWordProgress();
                       }else{
                           strikeLetters[strikes] = guess;
                           strikes++;
                           drawGallows();
                           drawStrikeLetters();
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }else{
       alert("The game is over");
   }
}
```

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hangman!</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

    </head>
    <body>

        <section id ="gallows">
            <p>section for picture of hanged man</p>
                <img id="gallowsimg" src="images/strike-0.png" alt="gallows">
            </section>

            <section id ="strikes">
                <p>strikes section shows incorrect guesses</p>
                <div id ="strikeLetters">
                    <p>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id ="correctword">
                <div id ="guessword">

                </div>
                <p>word section that shows the word being guessed correctly</p>
            </section>

            <section id ="guess-form">
                <p>guess section that contains form where player can type in a letter to guess</p>
                <form id="hangman">
                    <input type="text" name="letter" id="letter" placeholder="Guess a letter" />
                    <input id="guess" name="guess" type="submit" value="Guess" />
                </form>
            </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is giving another error  ```"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"```

Answer (score 0):

I think the original problem that you had was that you were trying to access the value of `hangman` when you should have been getting the value of `letter`.

That is: `document.getElementById("letter")` instead of `document.getElementById("hangman")`.

There were some other issues with how you were checking the correctness of the guess as well as incrementing `strikes`. I've replaced it with a `console.log` statement so that you can complete the rest.

```js
let word = 'hello';
let maxStrikes = 5;
let strikes = 0;
let revealedLetters = [];
let strikeLetters = new Array(maxStrikes); // this will contain every letter that has been incorrectly guessed.

drawWordProgress(); // run this now, to draw the empty word at the start of the game.

// Manipulates the DOM to write all the strike letters to the appropriate section in hangman.html
function drawStrikeLetters() {
    strikeL = document.getElementById("strikeLetters");
    let strikeText = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < strikeLetters.length; i++){
        strikeText += strikeLetters[i] + ", ";
        strikeL.innerHTML = "<p>" + strikeText + "</p>";
    }
    // your DOM manipulation code here
    // should create a String from strikeLetters and put that into the content of some element.
}

// Manipulates the DOM to write the successfully guessed letters of the word, replacing them with dashes if not yet guessed
function drawWordProgress() {
}

// Manipulates the DOM to update the image of the gallows for the current game state.
function drawGallows() {
}


document.getElementById("guess-form").addEventListener("submit", processGuess);

function processGuess(event){
   event.preventDefault();

   let guess = document.getElementById("letter").value;

   document.getElementById("letter").value.toUpperCase();
   document.getElementById("letter").value = "";

   if(strikes < maxStrikes) {
       let guessIsCorrect = false;
       if (word.indexOf(guess) !== -1) {
         console.log(`correct: ${guess}`);
       } else {
         console.log(`incorrect: ${guess}`);
       }
   }else{
       alert("The game is over");
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hangman!</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

    </head>
    <body>

        <section id ="gallows">
            <p>section for picture of hanged man</p>
                <img id="gallowsimg" src="images/strike-0.png" alt="gallows">
            </section>

            <section id ="strikes">
                <p>strikes section shows incorrect guesses</p>
                <div id ="strikeLetters">
                    <p>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id ="correctword">
                <div id ="guessword">

                </div>
                <p>word section that shows the word being guessed correctly</p>
            </section>

            <section id ="guess-form">
                <p>guess section that contains form where player can type in a letter to guess</p>
                <form id="hangman">
                    <input type="text" name="letter" id="letter" placeholder="Guess a letter" />
                    <input id="guess" name="guess" type="submit" value="Guess" />
                </form>
            </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

`.value` only works with `<input>`. Try using `.innerHTML` instead:

```
document.getElementById("hangman").innerHTML = document.getElementById("hangman").innerHTML.toUpperCase();
```